# Trimming C++ string in constant time

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

Is there a STL/library method to reduce the string size (trim it) in constant time.

In C this this can be done in constant time by just adding the '\0' past the last index.

C++ resize compexity is undefined and mostly likely be O(N)

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/resize/

Comment: Where are you getting this information from? What evidence do you have that C can resize a string in constant time?

Comment: It is true that `std::string::resize`'s complexity is formally `O(n)`. Yet, if you were to actually examine your C++ library's implementation when the string's size is reduced, you will be very much surprised as to the actual complexity of that particular operation.

Comment: Yes, it's O(n). But it must be, because if the new size exceeds the capacity, it must be re-allocated and copied. And even if it only enlarges the string, the new part must be initialized. Of course, if it doesn't get bigger, there is a constant amount of work. BTW: Pre-C++11 COW-strings it had to be O(n) in any case un-sharing would happen due to the modification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@SamVarshavchik is being coy in the comments, but it's worth spelling out: in many implementations, including libstdc++, `std::string::resize()` will reduce the size of a string in constant time, by reducing the length of the string and not reallocating/copying the data:
https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/basic_string.tcc . The estimate of O(n) is if you increase the size, forcing the string to be reallocated and copied over.

Alternatively, in C++17, `std::string_view` is rough immutable counterpart to "trimming" a C string by slapping a null byte. It takes a slice of a string (pointer + size) without copying its content, and you can then pass it around to various STL functions or print it from a stream.

```cpp
std::string hello_world = "hello world";
auto hello = std::string_view(hello_world.data(), 5);
std::cout << hello; // prints hello
```

The caveat is that the string_view doesn't own the data, so you can't use it once the original string goes out of scope, and you don't want to modify the original string in a way that might cause it to reallocate.

Answer (score 1):

The C++17 way, we can achieve the substr operation in O(1).

https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/c-17-avoid-copying-with-std-string-view

`std::string_view` do not allocate the memory on heap for large string as well.
`std::string` allocate memory on heap but exception is for `std::string` size is 15 for MSVC and GCC and 23 for Clang. `std::string` below above mentioned size are not allocated memory on heap.